# jQuery & SP2010 : Upload document to library using jQuery?

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, jquery, file-upload, spservices

I built a custom form that saves the data to multiple lists with on click; it works pretty well for its intended use (keeping the data related). Thing is I am totally new at jQuery and SPServices, but am learning.

I would like to know if SPService/jQuery will allow me to use the aspx control to upload a single document to a library? I have seen plugins out there for multiple file uploads so I assume this is possible, but all of these seem way to much for what I am trying to do, and I would like to learn how to do it.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Could provide simple example or explanation or reference?

Appreciate it as always!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same need and built my own jQuery widget... you can read more about it here:

http://paultavares.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/sharepoint-ui-widgets-upload-and-pickusers/

The zip file has a self-contained demo that demonstrate the use of the upload plugin. Make sure you have all the prerequisites in place.

Hope you find a good use for it.

Paul.

Comment: @Paul..so I am having trouble getting this to work. I have the webpart load to a page, and the library in a document library. Could you please provide an example of how you would use this via CEWP or something? Went through the zip and didn't see anything except webpart and library unless I missed something....also I am a beginner. :) thanks!

Comment: Justin, Let me first apologize for the very late response. For some reason I did recieve any notification on this thread. Are you still looking to get a working solution? If you have the webpart loaded, then you should a working demo. What trouble are having? Paul.

Comment: @PaulT. Looks like you had two accounts which is why you didn't get notified. I've fixed that for you!

Comment: @PaulT. is it possible to upload document along with some metadata. Suppose i want to pass the location and department information along with the document that i want to upload. is it possible?

Comment: @mihir no, not in the current version. But you can do a subsquent update (after upload is done) and update the item.

Comment: @PaulT. With your latest code from git hub, after I upload a document, it is showing property pane to fill. I dont want to display this. I just want to upload the document. How i can control this behavior.

Comment: @PaulT. I just want to upload the document and show the success message without filling these fields in `editform.aspx`. How I can do that.

Comment: @mihir - there might be a way to that.  Can you post to github issues?  https://github.com/purtuga/SPWidgets