# How to Upload File to Document Library using JavaScript Client Object Model?

Tags: document-library, client-object-model

I want to Upload File to a Document Library using JavaScript in SharePoint 2010.
I found that you can copy file from One Document Library to Another but you can't upload File using JavaScript on this [Forum](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/forum/sharepoint-2010-programming/add-file-into-folder-sharepoint-javascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/). I want to know exactly that is it really impossible or not. Please help me with that? Its Urgent..

Comment: You could try using an xhr put (or a WebDAV library), but there could be issues depending on your browser. (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536032/xhr-javascript-put-method) Once you upgrade to 2013, you can use CSOM's FileCreationInformation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on this
[jQuery & SP2010 : Upload document to library using jQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38968/jquery-sp2010-upload-document-to-library-using-jquery)

http://paultavares.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/sharepoint-ui-widgets-upload-and-pickusers/