# Document approval workflow in document library?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, approval

Do you know if it´s possible implement a document approval workflow only in one folder of the document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your designer workflow you can check the FOLDER name in the document URL I think. Only if its there then continue

Comment: Thanks! and if i like to hide a custom action that initiate workflow for other folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it following way

1. Design your workflow using SPD
2. Create a web part for uploading documents using [JCOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/54936/21421)
3. If someone uploads document in a particular folder, then trigger your workflow using [JCOM](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/08/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html)