# Upload file to document library using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I want to upload a word document to sharepoint document library using javascript (say for ex .Net site).

How can i achieve this?

Comment: @AmalHashim I am new to Sharepoint, don't have idea how to achieve this

Comment: In order to use JavaScript Client Object Model you need all JS files. These files reside in SharePoint server. So I don't think you can use it outside SharePoint. You can use SharePoint .Net Client Object Model I think.

Comment: @AmalHashim Can't i just copy all required js to my application, and then use javascript code to do this?

Comment: Is this useful - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn769086.aspx ?

Comment: @AmalHashim is correct, Sharepoint Client Object Model will be a good choice for you in this case

Comment: Related Question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/38968/20982

Comment: @PrashantBhojani : if you need to stick with JavaScript and don't want to use the COM, I would recommend using either REST or SPServices - either of which can be called using JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It's still quite uncomfortable to upload documents by using the JSOM API. But it's possible.

In your case your Word file must be not larger than 1.5 MB. Additionally the clients browser must support HTML5.

Here is a [code example](http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2013/02/using-jsom-to-write-small-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library/) (it references also the jQuery library):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Get the URI decoded host web URL
    // We will use this to get a context here to write data
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
});

function CreateFile()
{
    // Ensure the HTML5 FileReader API is supported
    if (window.FileReader)
    {
        input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
        if (input)
        {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedBinary;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("The HTML5 FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
    }
}

// Callback function for onload event of FileReader
function receivedBinary()
{
    // Get the ClientContext for the app web
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // Use the host web URL to get a parent context - this allows us to get data from the parent
    parentCtx = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    parentWeb = parentCtx.get_web();
    parentList = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileCreateInfo.set_url(file.name);
    fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());

    // Read the binary contents of the base 64 data URL into a Uint8Array
    // Append the contents of this array to the SP.FileCreationInformation
    var arr = convertDataURIToBinary(this.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    {
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(arr[i]);
    }

    // Upload the file to the root folder of the document library
    this.newFile = parentList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

    clientContext.load(this.newFile);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}

function onSuccess()
{
    // File successfully uploaded
    alert("Success!");
}

function onFailure()
{
    // Error occurred
    alert("Request failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());
}

// Utility function to remove base64 URL prefix and store base64-encoded string in a Uint8Array
// Courtesy: https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746
function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI)
{
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

    for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++)
    {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

When you work with larger files you must use the REST API following by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn292553.aspx).

Comment: Any particular reason to prefer an [AppContextSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850894.aspx) over a [ClientContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759.aspx)?

Comment: Using `readAsDataURL` requires you to convert from base64 to binary (with `atob`), and then convert back to base64 with `SP.Base64EncodedArray`. If you instead use `readAsBinaryString`, then you can replace the entire "convert" function with `var _array = this.result.split("").map(function (char) { return char.charCodeAt(0)})` and `var array = new Uint8Array(_array)` (Of course, for loop would be more performant in this case, but is still much simpler.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add metadata with file. Here is the link.

[File Upload with metadata](http://yeshagrawal.blogspot.in/2016/07/sharepoint-2013-upload-file-with.html)

Comment: do not post links only, put some extract from it along. Links may go down/ break after some time